# How do I search one array for terms in another array and then put the results into a third array?

Tags: arrays, perl, while-loop

I have an array of strings @array, and I want to search @array2 for terms in @array. @array2 contains two elements per row of data.

e.g.  @array = a b c d

@array2 has two columns with row entries:

```
row1: a x,     
row2: y c,     
row3: d x,     
row4: d c,     
row5: x b,     
row6: x x,     
row7: y x
```

If any $member of @array is in any row, I want to put those rows of @array2 into @array3 and ideally all in a single column, so @array3 = a x y c d x d c x b

i.e. rows 6 and 7 do not contain a, b, c or d so they are excluded!
any help would be great!

Comment: Are you overwriting or appending the file you put the strings in?  Additionally, your question is getting complicated, show some example inputs and what you expect as a result.

Comment: Of course it depends on the second file's size, but I would at least try to read the whole file into array. Finding intersected elements of these two arrays is a _lot_ more simple - and the code would be more maintainable, too. )

Comment: i've updated the problem description - hopefully it is more straightforward to read now!

Comment: If you want to ask a different question, please start a new thread instead of totally changing an older question.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `for` loop:

```
for my $member (@array) {
   ...
}
```

If you want to exhaust the array, you can use `shift` in a `while` loop:

```
while (@array) {
    my $member = shift @array;
}
```

You can even shorten it to

```
while (defined(my $member = shift @array)) { ... }
```

but only if you are sure all the members of the @array are defined.

Comment: using your last suggestion, in my first while loop to assign @array to a hash i use: `%members;

while (defined(my $member = shift @array)) {

if ($member =~ m/(\w+)/) {
    $members{$1} = 1;
}
}` but this seems to only have a single output??

Comment: my next while loop is to search @array2 as it were, or as a file in this case: `open(FILE2, $filename2);

while (my $member2 = <FILE2>) {
    
 if ($member2 =~ m/(\w+)/) {
     if (exists($members{$1})) {
         $member2 = <FILE2>;
         print $member;
     }
 } 
}

close FILE2;`

Comment: when you say use the for loop, do you mean instead of the while loop?

Answer (score 0):

use an array, for[each] construct may be more appropriate

```
@array=<FILE>;  # in array context <FILE> returns an array instead a line

while(@array>0) {  # in scalar context @array returns the size of the array
    my $line = shift @array;
    ...
}
```

or to preserve the array

```
my $i=0;
while($i<@array) {
  my $line = $array[$i];
  ...
} continue {
  $i++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option:

```
use Modern::Perl;

my @array  = qw/ a b c d /;
my @array2 = ( 'a x', 'y c', 'd x', 'd c', 'x b', 'x x', 'y x' );
my @array3;

for (@array2) {
    my @i = split;
    push @array3, @i if $i[0] ~~ @array or $i[1] ~~ @array;
}

say for @array3;
```

Output:

```
a
x
y
c
d
x
d
c
x
b
```

The `for` loop iterates over `@array2`'s elements, `split`ting the letters into `@i`.  The 'smart match' operator (Perl 5.10+) is used to see weather one or the other letter is in the list contained in `@array` and, if so, the list in `@i` is pushed onto `@array3`, which is finally printed.